# How to make a pandas dataframe from multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

As an output of my analysis, I get a dictionary containing the measurements for each sample. I would like to have these in a dataframe with a row for each sample (thus the dictionary). The dictionary for each sample has the same keys. Is there a way to efficiently add each dictionary as a row to a dataframe?

```
sample_1 = {"area": 2, "perimeter": 3, "diameter": 5}
sample_2 = {"area": 6, "perimeter": 3, "diameter": 8}
```

I want to combine these in a dataframe. The columns should be area, perimeter and diameter, and the rows should be the samples. I have over 5000 samples and 20 variables stored in the dictionaries.

I have tried the function `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` but this would result in having to turn each dictionary in a dataframe that then had to be merged.

I cannot change the output of the function I use to measure to a dataframe, so the dictionaries is what I have to work with.

Comment: Post working examples please! We shouldn't have to edit your code to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine all your samples in a list:

```
sample_1 = {'area': 2, 'perimeter': 3, 'diameter': 5}
sample_2 = {'area': 6, 'perimeter': 3, 'diameter': 8}

samples = [sample_1, sample_2]

out = pd.DataFrame(samples)
```

If you can, it's even better to drop the intermediate variable names:

```
samples = [{'area': 2, 'perimeter': 3, 'diameter': 5},
           {'area': 6, 'perimeter': 3, 'diameter': 8},
          ]

out = pd.DataFrame(samples)
```

Output:

```
   area  perimeter  diameter
0     2          3         5
1     6          3         8
```

If your samples have meaningful names:

```
sample_1 = {'area': 2, 'perimeter': 3, 'diameter': 5}
sample_2 = {'area': 6, 'perimeter': 3, 'diameter': 8}

samples = {'A': sample_1, 'B': sample_2}

out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(samples, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
   area  perimeter  diameter
A     2          3         5
B     6          3         8
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! I actually want the intermediate variable names as row names in the dataframe. Is there a way to do that with pd.DataFrame as well or should I create a list of those names and then add them with df.set_index()?

Comment: @MaaikevR - There are multiple ways to do that depending on how your code is setup. One option is to create a new key/value pair for each item as you stick it into the list. Maybe add `"index":"sample_1"`. Then, you can convert that column to the dataframe index.

Comment: @MaaikevR the best is to not use variable names but a dictionary with keys as the meaningful names: `samples = {'A': {'area': 2, 'perimeter': 3, 'diameter': 5}, 'B': {'area': 6, 'perimeter': 3, 'diameter': 8}}`. Always avoid having useless variables and go for container whenever you can.

Answer (score -1):

You can first transform your two dictionaries to dataframes with the following:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([sample_1], columns=['area', 'perimeter','diameter'])
df2=pd.DataFrame([sample_2], columns=['area', 'perimeter','diameter'])

frames = [df1, df2]
```

Next you can concat the two. Concating means to connect the two dfs horizontally:

```
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Your Output:

```
    area    perimeter   diameter
  0  2           3          5
  0  6           3          8
```